# New To C, Simple Loop

Tags: c

I have a file called testdata1 and I have 20 values of the same number in it. How can I add all these numbers and then print that number onto the screen. I currently have this, but I know that it's probably the worst way to do it and should probably use a loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
FILE* fin;
fin = fopen("testdata1.txt", "r");
int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10, n11, n12, n13, n14, n15, n16, n17, n18, n19, n20, sum;

fscanf(fin, "%d", &n1);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n2);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n3);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n4);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n5);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n6);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n7);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n8);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n9);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n10);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n11);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n12);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n13);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n14);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n15);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n16);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n17);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n18);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n19);
fscanf(fin, "%d", &n20);

sum = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 + n7 + n8 + n9 + n10 + n11 + n12 + n13 + n14 + n15 + n16 + n17 + n18 + n19 + n20;
printf("The sum of numbers is %d.\n", sum);
fclose(fin);

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `same number` and `loop` you already have a solution.

Comment: What's the format of the txt file?

Comment: Replace `n1`, `n2`, ..., `n20` by an array. (Remember that array indices start at zero.)

Comment: Or, we can also define a `n` and use it 20 times ;)

Answer (score 7):

You don't really need to use an array. Just add the numbers together as you read them in:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, n, sum = 0;
    FILE* fin = fopen("testdata1.txt", "r");
    if (!fin) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: Unable to open file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
        if (fscanf(fin, "%d", &n) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Error: Unexpected input\n");
            fclose(fin);
            return 1;
        }
        sum += n;
    }
    printf("The sum of numbers is %d.\n", sum);
    fclose(fin);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You should check if `fopen` was successful too

Comment: @CoolGuy I wrongly assumed that `fopen()` would throw an error instead of trying to dereference a null pointer. But no, you were right. Thanks for pointing that out :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're asking here but I'm pretty sure you're asking for a loop that can add all these values, so I'll go off of that.

First though there are some terrible mistakes in your design, the first of which is how you declare your variables. You really don't need to declare 20 variables. You can use two methods depending on your needs:

A. Declare an array in case you need to access all of those 20 variables later on as such: `int values[20]`

B. Declare two int variables at the top, one for the sum and one for storing the next number from the file

For case A it would look something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int sum, values[20];
    FILE* file = fopen("file");
    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
        if (fscanf(fin, "%d", &values[i]) != 1) {
            printf("%s\n","error handling here");
            fclose(fin);
            return 1;
        }
        sum += n;
    }
}
```

As for case B, well squeamish ossifrage already answered it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you should use a loop, no need for arrays this time; just replace the part where you read each number separatedly and put this:

```
for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
  fscanf(fin, "%d", &n1);
  sum += n1;
}
```

And there you go! your `sum` variable will hold the sum

Comment: ah, you are right @squeamishossifrage just did this by ear, shall replace the `while` loop with an `for`